# RoboGuice Proguard CreationException

Tags: java, android, guice, roboguice, roboblender

I'm using Roboguice 3.0.1 with RoboBlender  3.0.1. I've read the wiki. This application has been working perfectly since 3.0.1 has been GA (almost a year), and I just added proguard to my project. I've *seemingly* setup the proguard configuration correctly.

Anytime I run the application, I get this error immediately (this is all that is printed; no stack trace or anything).

```
11-24 01:36:05.473 12995-12995/com.me D/roboguice.RoboGuice: Using annotation database(s).
11-24 01:36:05.475 12995-12995/com.me D/roboguice.RoboGuice: Using annotation database(s) : [com.me, roboguice]
11-24 01:36:05.485 12995-12995/com.meD/roboguice.RoboGuice: Time spent loading annotation databases : 8
11-24 01:36:05.822 12995-12995/com.me E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.me, PID: <pid>
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.me.MeApplication: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
```

Note: I've posted this as an issue in the RoboGuice repo, but since that place looks dead, I figured I'd be more likely to get help here.

Comment: *"I've setup the proguard configuration correctly"* - What makes you so sure of that, especially since you seem to suggest this issue only surfaced when you added Proguard to your configuration? You could try running Proguard on your debug build type (if you hadn't yet) to get some more output. Also, if applicable, turn off obfuscation for now, while allowing Proguard to still strip code - that way you can more easily read any strack traces.

Comment: I'm sure of that because: A) I've followed all the guidelines in the RoboGuice wiki B) There were Proguard related crashes occurring, and then I fixed all of them C) I've verified that everything looks the way it should in classes.dex. I've only been running it on my debug build (experience has taught me to not release a build with Proguard until you're 1000% sure it works), and obfuscation is off. When I say that is all that is printed, I literally mean that is all the logcat printed.

Comment: Although, you raise a good point. See edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with Guice. There was an error at [this line](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/InternalInjectorCreator.java#L184), but no error was printed.

[Guice Issue](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/964)